# iOS Firewall Application

Tags: ios, iphone, port, firewall

My final project is to develop an iPhone application that allow/disallow applications to make data transfer via specific ports. For example; I want to allow appA to transfer data via port 80 from My Application.

Is it possible to make an app like this, if possible which libraries or what should I learn.

Thanks

Comment: Since this is a first-page search engine hit (and people are going to come here looking for answers on this), I figured I'd post links to a couple of my answers over on AskDifferent that shed some light on this topic, although they don't involve software development directly, but just the availability/feasibility of a firewall in general on iOS: [Does IPFW exist for iOS?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45022/18387) - [Does iOS have a firewall?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48109/18387)

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible, unless you want write your own web-browser.

Apple does not allow interaction with the system on the level needed to write an firewall app. All apps in iOS are sandbox and have limited interaction with the operating system and other app for security and privacy concerns.

If you are looking to build in it for jailbroke iOS devices then this might be possible but with the official SDK there is no way to do this.

You can write your own web-browser to allow acces to some site or not. If you want it system wide for outgoing call you might be able to use a proxy which you can control with your app, but if someone removes the proxy server in the settings.app the app is by passed.

Comment: Well, can I allow/disallow apps to make internet access or data transfer(without specific port)

Comment: Like I said in my answer: **NO** this not possible. Since you can not interact in that level in iOS.

Comment: My teacher said there's a way, but he didn't tell me. He said search and find yourself.

Comment: I can asure you there is no way to this in the official SDK, also Stackoverflow is not here to solve your homework.

Answer (score 1):

An answer from the 2021 future:

[Apple says](https://www.apple.com/ca/business-docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) they don't need a firewall per-se:

> Because iOS achieves a reduced attack surface by limiting listening ports and removing unnecessary network utilities such as telnet, shells, or a web server, **no additional firewall software is needed on iOS devices**

However,
Apple added support for [Network Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) in iOS 8.0, which you can use to create content filters (which, if Firewalls are no longer an issue, are your next concern):

> With the NetworkExtension framework, you can customize and extend the core networking features of iOS and macOS. Specifically, you can:
>
> - Change the system’s Wi-Fi configuration
> - Integrate your app with the hotspot network subsystem (Hotspot Helper)
> - Create and manage VPN configurations, using the built-in VPN protocols (Personal VPN) or a custom VPN protocol
> - **Implement an on-device content filter**
> - Create and manage system-wide DNS configurations, using the built-in DNS protocols or a custom on-device DNS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a firewall for iphone called Firewall iP 2.0. So it is possible as long as you know how to code it. Also, this requires you to JB your iphone.